# My Entity Data Model (ASP.NET MVC) that was generated is missing a View I created in my database.. why?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

I created my database in SQL Server, and then in Visual Studio I created an Entity Data Model using my database. Everything was generated fine, all my tables and views, EXCEPT for one particular view. The difference between this view and my other views is I use the `UNION ALL` in the view syntax. See below for the SQL view setup, and below that for my code in Visual Studio which complains about missing `v_contactMasterList`:

```
select clicontfin_cli_fk as clientPK,
contfin_firstName as FirstName, 
contfin_lastName as LastName, 
contfin_institutionName as InstitutionName,
contfin_contactType as ContactType 
from f_linkClientContactFinancial lccf
inner join f_contactFinancial cf on lccf.clicontfin_contfin_fk = cf.contfin_pk

UNION ALL

select clicontins_cli_fk as clientPK,
contins_agentFirstName as FirstName,
contins_agentLastName as LastName,
contins_agencyName as InstitutionName,
contins_contactType as ContactType
from f_linkClientContactInsurance lcci
inner join f_contactInsurance ci on lcci.clicontins_contins_fk = ci.contins_pk

UNION ALL

select clicontleg_cli_fk as clientPK,
contleg_FirstName as FirstName,
contleg_LastName as LastName,
contleg_firmName as InstitutionName,
contleg_contactType as ContactType
from f_linkClientContactLegal lccl
inner join f_contactLegal cl on lccl.clicontleg_contleg_fk = cl.contleg_pk

UNION ALL

select clicont_cli_fk as clientPK,
cont_FirstName as FirstName,
cont_LastName as LastName,
NULL as InstitutionName,
cont_contactType as ContactType
from f_linkClientContactPersonal lccp
inner join f_contactPersonal cp on lccp.clicont_cont_fk = cp.cont_pk
```

And my C# code is below - note, that where the `mainDB.v_contactMasterList.ToList()` is is where the problem is. It does NOT recognize the `v_contactMasterList` at all. It recognizes every other database object such as my tables and my other views:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var viewModel = new ClientContactInformationViewModel
                       {
                          ClientContactRecords = mainDB.v_contactMasterList.ToList()
                       };
   return View();
 }
```

Also, notice where I declared `SelectLifeManagementDBEntites`, how it sees that, which was created from my Entity Data Model, as well as EVERY SINGLE ONE of my other tables and views.

When I created this view, I just copied and pasted my SQL Syntax into the view SQL area, and executed it. I then saved it. I did get a dialog box saying that views containing UNION ALL operators cannot be graphically represented in the diagram layout. Which that's fine, but I don't know if that might be causing the problem. Please help???? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to have a Primary Key field included in the view in order for this to show up in my data model.